# converting date data type into varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I  have some dates fields in table. These columns contain dates in the following format:

```
mmddyy
```

For example:

```
31/12/2010 00:00:00:0000
```

I need to import these values into a table which is set to varchar and numeric and formats dates like this:

```
monthName varchar
Year numeric(4,0)
```

currently I'm using

```
INSERT INTO [School].[dbo].[TeacherAttendenceDet] 
            ([TeacherCode], 
             [MonthName], 
             [Year]) 
(SELECT MAX(employeecode), 
        Datename(MONTH, dateofjoining) AS MONTH, 
        Datepart(YEAR, dateofjoining)  AS DATE 
 FROM   employeedet 
 GROUP  BY dateofjoining)
```

but `datename()` gives result in date format.. I have to save it in `varchar` format

How can I do this? 
this is employeemast table:

```
EmployeeCode    numeric(5, 0)   
PayScaleCode    numeric(7, 0)   
DesignationCode varchar(50) 
CityCode    numeric(5, 0)   
EmployeeName    varchar(50) 
FatherName  varchar(50) 
BirthDate   varchar(50) 
DateOfJoining   varchar(50) 
Address varchar(150)
```

this is TeacherAttendenceDet table

```
TeacherCode numeric(5, 0)   Unchecked
Year    numeric(4, 0)   Unchecked
MonthName   varchar(12) Unchecked
```

i have to insert in teacherattendencedet table the monthname and year from employeemast

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: this is giving january that is write.. but when inserting this is giving error     The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.    i have to store month name and year seprately... how can i do that?

Comment: Can you post the table DDL also?

Comment: OK, so the problem really is: your `datejoining` is a varchar, but you would like to use the date functions on it..... judging from the error message, your string doesn't always contain a valid date, either.... since unfortunately, your format used isn't supported by SQL Server.....

Comment: yaaa... thats was the main mistake.... thax

Comment: But really: if it's a **date** - you should definitely store it as a **DATETIME** !

Comment: This format `31/12/2010 00:00:00:0000` is simply not supported by any of the SQL Server conversion formats.... since it's a DATE, I would think you might be able to forget about the time portion, right?? If you have `31/12/2010`, then you can use `CONVERT(DATETIME, datejoining, 103)` to get a DATETIME out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were in your position, I would do the following:

- update the `EmployeeMast` table by adding a **real** `DATETIME` column:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE dbo.EmployeeMast
    ADD JoinDate DATETIME
  ```
- then convert all those entries in `datejoining` into the new datetime column:

  ```
   UPDATE dbo.EmployeeMast
   SET JoinDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(datejoining, 1, 10), 103)
  ```
- then drop that old column

  ```
    ALTER TABLE dbo.EmployeeMast DROP COLUMN datejoining
  ```

Now, once you have a `DATETIME` column, you can start using the date functions on that!

Now, your INSERT statement should work - since it does get its values from a `DATETIME` column, it will be able to compute `DATENAME()` and `DATEPART()` !

If you want to have the year (as numeric) and the month (as string) for the join date for each entry, I would recommend adding two computed fields to your table - something like:

```
alter table dbo.EmployeeMast
  add JoinYear AS YEAR(JoinDate) PERSISTED

alter table dbo.EmployeeMast
  add JoinMonth AS DATENAME(MONTH, JoinDate)
```

With this, you now have two additional columns - `JoinYear` as a numeric, `JoinMonth` as a string - that will always reflect the year and month someone joined - based on `JoinDate`.

They're computed - you don't need to insert those - they'll be computed from the `JoinDate` automagically and will always be available to you. No conversion, no messy inserts - just insert your row with the `JoinDate` and you'll have the year and month available right away.

Comment: ya i can do this but i have requirement to fill the teacherattendencedet table with the current date also... what should i do for that?

Comment: @Sheetal Inani: same idea? Year and Month based on a date?? Just add computed columns there, too!