# converting date from varchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to change the date format of a column, the column is set as varchar column name date time. The problem is that i cannot actually change the data type because the data is automatically inputted by a PLC on the automation side. I need the date in a date or numeric value because when i run my queries i need to give the system a date range. I am trying to use substrings to work around this issue but am getting an error saying that the data type is out of range. here is the syntax of my query.

```
select cast(
     (substring(datetime, 1, 4) + '-' +
      SUBSTRING(DateTime, 5, 2) + '-' + 
      SUBSTRING(DateTime, 7, 2) + ' ' + '00:00:00.000') as dateTime) as "Date"
    , ID1
    , ID2
    ,  diameter
    , WeightTheoretical
    , WeightActual
    , StockType 
from table1 
where datetime is not null 
    and datetime <> '' 
    and datetime <> '0' 
order by "Date", ID1;
```

Edit- the date format is as such 20120622:00:00:00:000

Comment: when posting code please be sure to use the `{}` button to format the code.

Comment: Show an example of the dates you are trying to covnert.  I have found that cast(<val> as date) or cast(<val> as datetime) works in most cases.

Comment: Please add some value that are stored in that DateTime column.

Comment: What is the format of the date string? yyyy-mm-dd, yyyy-dd-mm, yyyymmdd ? The substring ranges make it look like it is yyyymmdd

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting date data type into varchar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582446/converting-date-data-type-into-varchar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks from your SQL that your date string is of the format `YYYYMMDD`

This should convert fine using either the `CAST` or `CONVERT` functions:

eg

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'20120601')
SELECT CAST('20120601' as datetime)
```

both return the expected value as a datetime.

EDIT: Based on the supplied format you specified, I'd use the `SubString` to chop the supplied data down a bit:

eg

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,SUBSTRING('20120601',1,8))
```

Comment: this seemed to fix it for meselect {(Cast(SUBSTRING(table.DateTime, 5, 2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(table.DateTime, 7, 2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(table.DateTime, 3, 2) as smalldatetime)) as "Date" from MPIPEID where ISDATE(SUBSTRING(MPIPEID.DateTime, 5, 2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(table.DateTime, 7, 2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(table.DateTime, 3, 2)) = 1 order by "Date";}

Comment: aargh. That's pretty hard to read though, and will slow with all that string processing.

Comment: Sorry about the readability. Yeah i just wanted to post that encase anyone in the future has a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your date is with the format `yyyymmdd`, you can convert the varchar to datetime like this:

```
select convert(datetime, columname, 112)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the format of your data in the table (`20120622:00:00:00:000`) you can do the following:

```
declare @date varchar(50)
set @date = '20120622:00:00:00:000'

select cast(left(@date, 8) as datetime)
```

or

```
select convert(datetime, left(@date, 8))
```

results:

```
2012-06-22 00:00:00.000
```